# Is this predicate logic formula a tautology

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

> Is the following predicate logic formula a tautology
>   $$(\forall{x})(\forall{y})(\alpha(x,y)\lor\alpha(y,x))$$

So I'm pretty lost in this problem, I know how to read this predicate and everything but how do I check if it is a tautology?

What I thought of doing was writing down possible tables of truth values for $\alpha(x,y)$

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{$\alpha$}} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{x}}
& \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{y}}\\\
 x                                       & \top & \perp\\\
 y                                       & \perp  & \top
\end{array}
$$

In this example that I wrote down it would be that the predicate equation is not a tautology but this feels pretty incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the formula is not *valid*.

And, in general, we cannot test a formula of predicate logic with truth-table.

For a counter-example, consider the interpretation with domain $\mathbb N$ and interpret formula $\alpha$ with the binary relation $\lt$, i.e.

> $\mathbb N \vDash \alpha(x,y) [x/n,y/m] \text { iff } n < m$.

Obviously, it is not true that $n < m \lor m < n$, for every $n,m$.

Comment: This was a question on the last years exam, what should I write down in this case as an answer?

Comment: @Aleksa - I assume that with *tautology* it is meant "valid"; if so, the formual is not a tautology.

Comment: Yes very possible, could you explain me in that case how should I check for validity? Edit: I'm not doing this in english so I probably didn't translate things correctly.

Comment: Obviously, it is not a tautology also if we read "tautology" in the propositional sense.

Comment: @Aleksa - to show that a predicate logic formula is *valid*, you have to use a proof: either a semantical one or a derivation in some proof system (e.g. Natural Deduction).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and research this now